# Randomize 2 numpy arrays the same way

Tags: python, numpy, random, numpy-ndarray, python-3.8

I have 2 `np.ndarray()` objects and I want to randomize (or shuffle) them like this:

```
>>> a
[[12. 13. 24. ... 23. 45. 67.] [32. 10. 23. ... 23. 45. 67.] [12. 13. 24. ... 23. 45. 67.] ... [12. 13. 24. ... 23. 45. 67.]]
>>> b
[0. 0. 0. ... 1.]
>>> shuffle(a, b)
>>> a
[[12. 13. 24. ... 23. 45. 67.] [32. 10. 23. ... 23. 45. 67.] [12. 13. 24. ... 23. 45. 67.] ... [12. 13. 24. ... 23. 45. 67.]]
>>> b
[1. 0. 0. ... 0.]
```

Every number from the variable `b` corresponds to a label for my AI training data in the variable `a`.

Comment: `a` is not being shuffled at all, according to your output. So why not just `from numpy import random` and then `random.shuffle(b)`?

Comment: The actual code needs to shuffle both of them the same way as I described it. I didn't shuffle it in the example because I was too lazy to shuffle them ;)

Comment: Not really, he just has, what seem to be, almost identical rows.

Comment: Do check my solution which has multiple ways you could do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Numpy

You can use `np.c_` to shuffle them together and then put them back into your separate arrays -

```
import numpy as np

#Creating same X and y for demonstration
X = np.arange(0,10).reshape(5,2)
y = np.arange(0,10).reshape(5,2)

c = np.c_[X,y]
np.random.shuffle(c)

X1, y1 = c[:,:X.shape[1]], c[:,:y.shape[1]]

print(X1)
print(y1)
```

```
# Note, same order remains

[[8 9]
 [0 1]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [2 3]]

[[8 9]
 [0 1]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [2 3]]
```

---

### Using Sklearn

A better option would be to use sklearn api -

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X, y = shuffle(X, y, random_state=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! sklearn worked better for me!

Comment: glad to help. you can actually put more arrays in the shuffle to work  as well.. example for X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know that!

Comment: Yup and the random_state will let you reproduce the same shuffling each time with the same integer value.